# DotTrace, Is it possible to change Profiling type ie from Sampling to Tracing without killing profiling session?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, dottrace

I am using DotTrace 2018.3 to profile a MVC5 Web App on IIS Express, within Visual Studio 2017.

I start by profile using the "Sampling" profile Type. Is it possible to change the profile type to "Tracing" or "Line-by-Line" without stopping and restarting the profile session?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, it is not possible to change a profiling type without restarting a profiling session due to technical limitations.